# Integrate sms API with django prject

Tags: django, api, sms

i have my django project and i want to integrate it with Etisalat API to be able to send sms to client ,anyone can help me out to integrate SMS API with my project ?

Answer (score 0):

[Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) supports sending SMS messages, and I believe it can also carry out certain actions on receiving an SMS. It has a [Python API client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) so it should in principle be practical to integrate it with your application.

Answer (score 0):

I see PHP library with Etisalat, i can help you get it integrated with your django projects with API, I am expert in Twilio API too, you can reach me by sending mail to simer169 at gmail